# How to use name pattern in BasicThreadFactory?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on a multithreaded application that reads data from a number of sources, does some calculations and writes results to several outputs. I do have several reader threads, several calculation threads and several writers. Number of each types of threads are given in configuration.
I would like to have these threads named accordingly: "reader-1", "reader-2", "writer-1", etc.

So, I wanted to use org.apache.commons.lang3.concurrent.BasicThreadFactory for this purpose.
I did write the following code:

```
    BasicThreadFactory threadFactory = new BasicThreadFactory.Builder()
            .namingPattern("%s-%d")
            .daemon(false)
            .priority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
            .build();
    ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(config.getPoolSize(), threadFactory);
```

However, I cannot find anywhere how can I specify name and number of the working thread upon submission.
I searched hundreds of links and did not see a single example of how do I the do it.
I am creating my Callable

```
Callable reader = new BatchFileReader(config);
for(int i = 1; i <= maxReaders; i++) {
   executors.submit(reader);
}
```

Submit method does not have any other parameters except Runnable/Callable instance. I cannot figure out where I can specify string "reader" and it sequential number to the thread factory.
If anyone can give me a hint, I will appreciate it greatly.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked but when I did, I too failed to find how to configure thread names with existing factories. I needed to implement my own and manually assign a name to the thread in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to set the name of the `Thread` which executes a submitted `Callable`/`Runnable` just give the name to the `Callable`/`Runnable` and let it set the name of the `Thread` it is running on, by just calling `Thread.currentThread().setName(...)`, ie:

```
public class BatchFileReader implements Runnable {
    private final String name;

    public BatchFileReader(final String name /*, other arguments go here...*/) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(name);
        //Do your work here...
    }
}
```

I am expecting this to work independently of any `Executor` implementation, assuming that each `Thread` can only run one given task at a time, which as far as I know is the case indeed. If a single `Thread` may run more than one `Callable`/`Runnable` at a time in (pseudo-)parallel then this approach won't work.

I also looked at subclassing each provided `Executor` implementation, but that would be a bit more pain. At least on `ThreadPoolExecutor` you can achieve this by subclassing it and overriding `ThreadPoolExecutor#beforeExecute` and both `AbstractExecutorService#newTaskFor` methods in case you are using any `submit` method to submit `Callable`s/`Runnable`s. If you are just using `execute` for a `Runnable` then you will only need to override `ThreadPoolExecutor#beforeExecute`. But then again you would have to keep a reference to the `Runnable`'s name inside it (so that you can pass it over to the `Thread` in `ThreadPoolExecutor#beforeExecute`).

Another thing I noticed lies on the question if you really have to rely on `Thread`s for their name at all... I mean if you are just interacting with the `Callable`s/`Runnable`s inside their `call`/`run` method that *you* provide, then why not just simply provide *them* with their name and that's all? I mean I don't know why you need at all to provide a name to internally handled `Thread`s anyway, by the time you are only interacting with their `Callable`s/`Runnable`s (assuming you are doing so). As far as I understand, you could just provide an accessor method for the name (ie a `getName`) in your `BatchFileReader` implementations.

Comment: I came up to the similar solution on my own. Just passing to the constructor not the name, but a number and class itself construct the name "reader-N", "writer-M", etc.
Apparently this BasicThreadFactory implementation is a half-cooked idea. It is useless.